# How to define constructor function with destructuring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, destructuring

I want to build a `Vehicle` class to create objects based on it. And I want to pass an object to the constructor function as a parameter such that `const vehicle = new Vehicle({vehicleType: 'car', name: 'car1', range: 500})`

I have built it like below but how can I destructure the constructor parameter in order to avoid repeating 'options.' word?

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor(options = { vehicleType: 'car', name: '', range: '', seats: '' }) {
    this.vehicleType = options.vehicleType
    this.name = options.name
    this.range = options.range
    this.seats = options.seats
  }

  getRangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  multiplySeatsBy(count) {
    this.seats *= count
    return this
  }

  getSeatCount() {
    return this.seats
  }

  get rangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  
}
```

Comment: `constructor ({ vehicleType = 'car', name = '', range = '', seats = '' } = {})`

Comment: `Object.assign(this, options);`.

Comment: Looks good. Why don't we use colon but equal mark like this ? constructor ({ vehicleType : 'car', name =:'', range =:'', seats : '' } = {})

Comment: @CelalettinTurgut Because that is how the language architects of JavaScript decided how default values should be set. It's the same as the `options = ...` in your code.

Comment: You can also combine the two first comments, pass the arguments as CherryDT has adviced, then do `Object.assign(this, {vehicleType, name, range, seats});` in the constructor, you'll get rid of all the `this.x = ...` lines.

Comment: @Teemu Did you mine? `constructor(options = { vehicleType: 'car', name: '', range: '', seats: '' }) {
    Object.assign(this, options)
  }`

Comment: Yep, that'll work too.

Comment: Thank yo so much. I can accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
class Vehicle {
  constructor(options) {
    const { vehicleType = 'car', name = '', range = '', seats = '' } = options;
    this.vehicleType = vehicleType
    this.name = name
    this.range = range
    this.seats = seats
  }

  getRangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  multiplySeatsBy(count) {
    this.seats *= count
    return this
  }

  getSeatCount() {
    return this.seats
  }

  get rangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  
}
```

Comment: You're still repeating the options variable?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
class Vehicle {
  vehicleType = 'car';
  name = '';
  range = '';
  seats = '';

  constructor(options) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }

  getRangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

  multiplySeatsBy(count) {
    this.seats *= count
    return this
  }

  getSeatCount() {
    return this.seats
  }

  get rangeToSeatsRatio() {
    return this.range / this.seats
  }

}
```

Comment: The destructuring is missing, otherwise one could assign via options whatever additional properties.